# How to delete a widget from a stacked widget in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, widget, nokia

Using `QStackedWidget` to switch between the views, I will be able to traverse between the views.

I am facing problem in some scenarios, where I do not require the widgets, but I want to remove them completely.

`QStackedWidget` provides the functionality to remove widgets, still the ownership of the widget will be there, I mean widget will be hidden.

I don't want this to be happen - when I call remove widget it should be deleted. How should I handle this?

Comment: Are you creating the object on the stack, or on the heap but in a QStackedWidget?  The question title implies the former, the question text implies the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried simply deleting the object after removing it?  i.e.

```
stackWidget->removeWidget(myWidget);
delete myWidget;
```

Comment: The documentation of QStackedWidget::removeWidget is confusing: ownership _does_ transfer back to the application, and it's correct to delete/free the widget after calling removeWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Many Qt objects will get automatically removed when deleted.  (At least, in the QtGraphics API things work that way)  I suspect that simply deleting the object will also remove it, since Qt Objects do emit a signal that they have been deleted.

Comment: you think, i have a member variable or local variable, i will assign memory dynamically, in this case when i delete object those members and local variable deleted automatically? or we need to do manual delete?